# jQuery code works only after 2nd click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a jQuery plugin which has following configuration to run:

```
$('#colorSelector').ColorPicker({

});
```

However, I need to add this to a div dynamically added with the jQuery, therefore I am using following:

```
$(document).on('click', '#colorSelector', function(){

    $(this).ColorPicker({

    });

});
```

With the above method, it works but only after clicking couple of times. It does not work on the first click. How can I make it work on the first click.

**Demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/G8yBX/

Comment: Couldn't you add the colorpicker when you append the div? I imagine you could just chain it. Something like: $("<div></div>").appendTo("#divtoappendto").ColorPicker({});

Answer (score 2):

Once you dynamically add the div, call `ColorPicker` on it immediately after, else you need to click once to activate the code (as you can see in your demo).

Comment: Can you give an example, please?

Comment: This is the right answer -- should have read it before I answered

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use delegation for this, you'll have to make sure you aren't re-initializing it on each click by using an additional class, then at the end you'll want to re-trigger the click event and prevent this one from completing.

```
$(document).on('click', '#colorSelector:not(.cp)', function(){

    $(this).addClass('cp').ColorPicker({
        color: '#0000ff',
        onShow: function(colpkr) {
            $(colpkr).fadeIn(200);
            return false;
        },
        onHide: function(colpkr) {
            $(colpkr).fadeOut(200);
            return false;
        },
        onChange: function(hsb, hex, rgb) {
            $('#colorSelector div').css('backgroundColor', '#' + hex);
            $('#colorSelector input').val('#' + hex);
        }
    }).click();
    return false; 

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Tentonaxe/G8yBX/12/

I would instead use the success callback of whatever is generating the colorpicker.

Comment: This won't trigger on clicking on the color.  The picker triggers when you click the colored box.  What's wrong with click?

Comment: Nothing, i should have left it as click

Comment: The downside of using click is it won't trigger when you tab to the input.

Comment: Oddly, it doesn't appear that this extension triggers on focus anyway.

Comment: you're right... i wonder if that's just an oversight, or if it was on purpose. Likely an oversight.

Comment: No it's accessible (aria)

Answer (score 1):

Only call it once; no need to be nested in a document event.

```
$('#colorSelector').ColorPicker({
    color: '#0000ff',
    onShow: function(colpkr) {
        $(colpkr).fadeIn(200);
        return false;
    },
    onHide: function(colpkr) {
        $(colpkr).fadeOut(200);
        return false;
    },
    onChange: function(hsb, hex, rgb) {
        $('#colorSelector div').css('backgroundColor', '#' + hex);
        $('#colorSelector input').val('#' + hex);
    }
});
```

---

You can bind it in the event that adds the element, if that's your goal.

Answer (score -1):

Seems like you'll have to initialize it first, and then call `show()`:

http://jsfiddle.net/G8yBX/6/

Comment: You don't need to call show at all if it's already initialized.  http://jsfiddle.net/G8yBX/8/

Comment: After looking at it again.  All that show is doing is showing the `#colorSelector` div which is already visible.  It essentially does nothing.